# Solve for eigenvector as rational function of eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rational-functions

Let $A$ be an $n$ by $n$ matrix with entries in $\{0,1\}$, and such that some power $A^k$ is strictly positive, so Perron-Frobenius stuff applies, i.e. there is a real top eigenvalue $\lambda$ with multiplicity $1$. Let $v$ be a corresponding eigenvector, $Av = \lambda v$.

**Q:** Is it always possible to write $v$ as a quotient of polynomials in $\lambda?$ If so, is there a simple procedure to determine those rational functions? I'm also wondering if the tools to do this in Python (or Sage perhaps?) already exist, i.e. given the matrix $A$, spit out an explicit expression for the eigenvector $v$ in terms of $\lambda$.

A bit of guessing works for small examples, e.g.:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

has characteristic polynomial $x^3 - x^2 - x - 1$, with top eigenvalue $\lambda \approx 1.839$, and with a bit of elbow grease, $v = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \lambda - 1 \\ \lambda^{-1} \end{bmatrix}$ is a corresponding (right) eigenvector. I want to be able to do the same thing in general.

I'm particularly interested in the $8$ by $8$ matrix

$\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0 \\ 1& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0 \\ 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 1 \\ 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

If someone can handle this guy, even with ad-hoc ideas, it would be helpful!

**Edit:** Ok, the 8x8 matrix isn't too hard to do by hand. So it's not so enlightening regarding a general method.

**Edit 2:** To clarify, I'm looking for a formula or method that's simpler than Gaussian elimination or the like. There are sometimes clever methods for these sorts of things -- the 'cover up' method for partial fractions comes to mind.

Comment: For general reasons, the entries of $v$ can always be chosen to be polynomials in $\lambda$ with rational coefficients.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan do you have a quick proof? Or a standard reference?

Comment: You want to find a vector in the kernel of $A - \lambda$. The entries of $A - \lambda$ are rational polynomials in $\lambda$, or equivalently elements of the number field $\mathbb{Q}[\lambda]$. Now perform row reduction on it; the result is a row reduced matrix whose entries still lie in $\mathbb{Q}[\lambda]$, and if you unwind all the row reductions to see what this implies about eigenvectors you'll see that the eigenvector gets constructed using operations that begin and stay in $\mathbb{Q}[\lambda]$ the whole time.

Comment: Doesn't this give you rational functions in $\lambda$, not necessarily polynomials? (i.e. quotients of polynomials)

Comment: This is not an issue for two different reasons; 1) since eigenvectors are only defined up to scale you can clear denominators, 2) you don’t even have to do that because number fields are fields so you can divide by polynomials in $\lambda$ and get other polynomials in $\lambda$.

Comment: Aha, yes. And we can assume they're monic polynomials of degree at most $n-1.$

Comment: @JRichey I'm not sure if it's "simpler" than Gaussian elimination, but here is a "formula" that works in the case that $\lambda$ has algebraic multiplicity $1$ (which is guaranteed, for instance, if $A$ is an irreducible non-negative matrix, as is the case for your examples). Any non-zero column of the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) $\mathrm{adj}(A - \lambda I)$ will be a suitable eigenvalue, and each entry is expressible as a polynomial of the entries of $A$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann this is a useful observation, mathematicia happily computes the adjugate even with variable input. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

The following is an elaboration of my comment.

If $\lambda$ is of algebraic multiplicity $1$ (which is guaranteed in the case that $\lambda$ is the spectral radius and $A$ is an irreducible non-negative matrix, as is guaranteed by the Perron Frobenius theorem), then the desired eigenvector can be computed as any non-zero column of the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) $\operatorname{adj}(A - \lambda I)$.

The fact that $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is non-zero follows from the fact that $\lambda$ has geometric multiplicity $1$, which means that $A - \lambda I$ has rank $n-1$, which as a consequence of the determinantal characterization of rank means that at least one of the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrices of $A - \lambda I$ has a non-zero determinant. On the other hand, we have
$$
(A - \lambda I) \operatorname{adj}(A - \lambda I) = \det(A - \lambda I) I = 0,
$$
which means that each column of $\operatorname{adj}(A - \lambda I)$ is an element of $\ker(A - \lambda I)$, i.e. an element of the eigenspace of $A$ associated with $\lambda$.